# How to compute the sum of the products of all elements in a subset?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Given a set $S=\{1..n\}$ and all it's subsets $Q$ of size $m$, we  have:

$|Q| = \binom{n}{m}$

I would like to find a generic formula for the sum of products of all elements in each of the subsets. E.g. for $n=4, m= 2$:

$1 * 2 + 1 * 3 + 1 * 4 + 2 * 3 + 2 * 4 + 3 * 4$

Answer (score 2):

These are Stirling numbers of the first kind. These satisfy the generating
function
$$x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n-1)=\sum_{k=1}^n s(n,k)x^k.$$
So the solution to your problem is $s(n+1,n+1-k)$.